# Magento 2.3.4 product shows a blank page after migration process

Tags: magento, magento2

After migrating from  Magento 1.9.3 to Magento 2.3.4 I can see a blank product page.

For the solution, after checking that when product is saved from admin side I am then able to see product page and visible.

Another one I can see that ,

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected.

Is this any layout issue occurs this problem or image issue is making this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have used the Custom Layout Update field in Magento 1.9.

If you search in your database table 'catalog_product_entity_text' in the field 'value' for reference it should return the problem products.

See here for the new way to use product page custom layout updates:
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/override-magento-2-layout-product-page-example/